# Matrix computation

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a `384*512*3` `RGB` matrix. There are only `512` unique colors which repeat themselves with different weights. From them, I have to select half, and the other half must be replaced with the closest elements from the first one.

I thought of looping through the image, and search the closest color for the current one. After finding it, I replace one with the other.

But I have 3 loops `1:384`, `1:512`, `1:256`. With the first two I loop through the RGB matrix, the third is used to loop to the matrix containing the final colors. This takes some time to compute.

What can be done to speed it up?

The loops look like this:

```
dim=size(RGB);
for i=1:dim(1)
    for j=1:dim(2)
        aux=[RGB(i,j,1) RGB(i,j,2) RGB(i,j,3)];
        minim=RGB_dist(uint8(V_colors_K(1,1:3)),aux);
        index=1;
            for k=1:K
            %index=1;
            if (minim>RGB_dist(uint8(V_colors_K(k,1:3)),aux))
                minim=RGB_dist(uint8(V_colors_K(k,1:3)),aux);
                index=k

            end
            RGB(i,j,1)=V_colors_K(index,1);
            RGB(i,j,2)=V_colors_K(index,2);
            RGB(i,j,3)=V_colors_K(index,3);
        end
    end
end
```

`V_colors_K` represent the half colors selected to be the final ones.

There is some minor improvement I could think about. The minimum distance is not needed if the color is in the `good` half.

Here's the algorithm to be more precise:

Definition 1. Function D(c1,c2) is the distance
between two color vectors c1 and c2, such as
Euclidean distance.

Definition 2. Function P(c) is the pixel number of
color c.
Definition 3. Base-color cbase of an initial color set
Q is the color that satisfies the equation

[image]

Definition 4. A weighted product of color c, V(c),
is defined as

[image]

where wp is the weight of the number of pixels,
and wd is the weight of a color distance.

Given the first color cbase, our method calculates
the weighted products of other colors and selects
the first K-1 largest product. The corresponding
K-1 colors with the base-color are used to
form an initial palette. The left N–K colors are merged with the closest colors in the initial
palette to produce the final palette.

RGB_dist function:

```
function[distance]=RGB_dist(x,y)

    distance=sqrt(sum((double(x-y)).^2*[3;4;2],2));

end
```

I do have a function that works on a whole matrix, it calculates the distance between all pairs.

```
function[D]=RGB_dist_full_2(x)

I = nchoosek(1:size(x,1),2);

D = squareform(RGB_dist(x(I(:,1),:), x(I(:,2),:)))

end
```

Then, I would need to get the minimum on each column.

Comment: how do you select half the colors? what is the process?

Comment: Can we see what you're doing inside the loop? In general you shouldn't ever be looping over matrices in matlab, almost all matlab functions that work on a single number will also work on a whole matrix all at once which will be 1000's of times faster.

Comment: @shoham I compute a product between the number of pixels that have that color and its distance to the base color, which is the one that appears the most in the image. One color is the base color ant the rest(half-1) are sorted in descending order based on the computed product.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth I added the loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, you are applying the operation `RGB_dist()` pairwise to every color in `V_colors_k` and every pixel in `RBG`. If `RGB_dist()` is a linear function, like a dot product then you can apply it to the whole matrix all at once. For example if it was a dot product then you could replace the entire inner loop with:

```
DISTS = V_colors_K * RGB(i,j,:)';
k = find( DISTS == min(DISTS(:)) );
RGB(i,j,:) = V_colors_K(k,:);
```

Without knowing what's in `RBG_dist()` I can't give you a better answer. The general answer that I can give is: Matlab loops are slow, if you want it to run fast you need to remove all loops and use only matrix operations (which are lightening fast). This process of replacing loops with matrix ops is called *vectorizing your code*, and it can be tricky. Without knowing what you're doing inside `RBG_dist()` it's impossible to come up with a full vectorization for you.

My usual workflow in matlab is to write something the intuitive way with loops, like you did, then once it gives me the correct results I go back and figure out how to vectorize it (ie replace all loops with matrix operations) to make it fast. Vectorizing is tricky, it's like a linear-algebra puzzle and the speeding-up always take me WAY longer than writing the code in the first place.

UPDATE:

The best I got uses one loop over your basis colors. You were super close with your RGB_dist function since that line will work perfectly well on whole matrices:

```
[RGBwidth RGBHeight RGBdepth] = size(RGB);
minDists=inf( [RGBwidth RGBheight] );
bestKs=zeros( [RGBwidth RGBheight] );
for k=1:K
    % make matrix out of the color k, the same shape as RGB
    color_K_mat = premute(repmat(V_colors_K(k,:), [RGBwidth 1 RGBheight]), [3 1 2]);

    % compute the distance from each pixel's color to color k
    dists = sqrt(sum((RGB-color_K_mat).^2, 3));

    % create a binary mask showing which pixels are closer to this color than to any previous one
    mask = (dists < minDists);

    % update your results matrices
    bestKs = not(mask)*bestKs + mask*k
    minDists = min(bestKs, dists);
end

% now bestKs(i,j) gives you the index k of the closest color for pixel (i,j)
% and minDists(i,j) gives you the distance to that color
```

In theory it should be possible to vectorize out even this loop, but that's a bigger puzzle and I have my own work to do :P

Comment: I updated my question. Have you thought of a better solution?

Comment: I really don't like doing all of the work for someone, but here you go.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth - You've done way more than you needed to, but I hope the OP can take something away from this and learn something.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`kmeans`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html):

```
img = im2double( img );
[IDX,C] = kmeans( reshape( img, [], 3 ), 256 ); %// cluster into 256 clusters
cimg = ind2rgb( reshape( IDX, size(img(:,:,1)) ), C );
```

Comment: I already use k-means to reduce the image to a reasonable number of colors. After that, I need to apply the algorithm I specified to @shoham in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

to reduce the inner loop operations:

1. define a vector the size of V_colors_K, with all the values assigned as aux (lets call it v_aux).
2. then calculate RGB_dist on v_aux vs V_colors_K.
3. take the minimum result (it represents the minimum distance color).